# xData.ResponseXML is undefined in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

Have Migrated from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013, after migration xData.responseXML  undefined.
[image]

In SharePoint 2010 working fine with xData.responseXML, but not working in SharePoint 2013 itemCount value is showing undefined because the xData.responseXML is undefined.

var itemCount = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("rs:data").attr("ItemCount");

Please help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the version of SPService library and jQuery library. The example code below for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "customlist",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        if(Status=="success"){
            var itemCount=$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("rs:data").attr("ItemCount");
            alert(itemCount);
        }else{
            alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
        }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

In SharePoint 2013, we can use REST API and jQuery Ajax to achieve the same requirement.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var listName="customlist";
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+listName+"')/ItemCount",
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var itemCount=data.d.ItemCount;
            alert(itemCount);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
});
</script>
```